# URL not being mapped correctly going through pages

Tags: java, css, spring, jsp

My root URL keep messing up in the Spring MVC application. I have the following resource defined in `servlet-context.xml`

```
<!-- Resource Mapping -->   
<resources mapping="/theme1/**" location="/resources/theme1/" cache-period="31556926"/>
```

On the header of `localhost:8080/me/login.jsp` I have the following CSS file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="theme1/css/main.css" type="text/css"></link>
```

Now on the same JSP, I have an anchor text `register` which maps to `/useraccount/register`.T

The method in my controller returns the same view, `login.jsp`. So after a page refresh, the domain is changed to `localhost:3000/me/useraccount/register`

So the problem is that style sheet URL becomes invalid - return 404. It now points to

```
localhost:8080/me/useraccount/theme1/css/main.css
```

How do can I fix this so it points back to - in a sense being static - to

```
localhost:8080/me/theme1/css/main.css
```

Comment: please change the context path to "/" follow article for how to change  https://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/eclipse-how-to-change-web-project-context-root/

Comment: @ManojKrishna how will that change anything? Please note, I want to deploy this application on AWS later. Is this step necessary?

Comment: no while deploying to AWS later you can delpoy as  ROOT.war ex: https://www.baeldung.com/tomcat-root-application

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. I changed my context from `/me` to `/`. The only difference it had made is the URL now points to `localhost:8080/useraccount/theme1/css/main.css` :-/

Comment: The only way to make it work is putting `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` at the root of the href link the CSS file.